# /dev/nvidiactl not present

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I have an NVIDIA GT 540M (based on `lspci` output) graphics card and am trying to install its drivers. I have tried various options like downloading from NVIDIA's [website](http://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in), CUDA 4.2 homepage (Cannot post more than 2 links) and apt-get (`apt-get install nvdia-current`) (also through "Additional Drivers" app, but I guess it is same as apt-get) but I am unable to install it. After searching online, it seems I should have files like /dev/nvidia** but I don't have it.

nvidia-smi always returns the same error:

```
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidiactl (No such file or directory).
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with NVIDIA driver. Make sure that latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/installing-cuda-5-on-ubuntu-12-04/) too.

And everytime I install the driver, my resolution drops to 640x480 and no matter what is doesn't change. I have to `apt-get purge nvidia*` then install xserver again to get it back right, or reinstall Ubuntu.

I have installed Ubuntu 4 times already to get this right, but nothing works. Can someone please help me out with this.

I have a 32-bit system running Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks

Comment: I just discovered I have exactly the [same problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2080615&s=8ac32e5d713a13ce4a57cd6a380a7b83&p=12336809#post12336809), windows shows 525M and ubuntu shows 540M!