# Ubuntu shows wrong graphics card

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS on my Dell Inspiron laptop. I have an Nvidia GeForce GT 525M graphics card but lspci shows 540M? I am unable to install nvidia drivers for this card now.

I also asked another question about unable to install nvidia drivers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271227/dev-nvidiactl-not-present).

I tried the solution mentioned in [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2075423&s=f7c2f3d8976b7cac8b9d9bd077155d7c&p=12315916#post12315916) answer, but doesn't work.

Sorry if it is inappropriate to ask two questions about the same thing...

## **Edit:**

Result of

```
lspci| grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)

optirun glxspheres
[ 1053.429303] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the

[ 1053.429348] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Comment: These two cards are **identical** aside from how fast the core/processor and memory runs on the cards.

Comment: See the comment made by Lekensteyn here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/240825/how-to-make-nvidia-optimus-gt540m-work-on-ubuntu-12-10  Here too the next comment states it DOES work. If not it might be worth while to edit your question with the results from the commands used in that topic.

Comment: Rinzwind: Thanks for the solution, now I do have some drivers installed, but on running a simple CUDA program it shows `CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version`. Would you be able to help out with this?